# Are the values defined in this JavaScript object actually functions?

Tags: javascript, wit.ai

I'm new to JavaScript, and after reading "JavaScript The Good Parts" I wanted to code something for fun. I stubled upon this code snipped that I can't understand:

```
const actions = {
  say(sessionId, context, message, cb) {
    console.log(message);
    cb();
  },
  merge(sessionId, context, entities, message, cb) {
    // Retrieve the location entity and store it into a context field
    const loc = firstEntityValue(entities, 'location');
    if (loc) {
      context.loc = loc;
    }
    cb(context);
  },
  error(sessionId, context, error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  },
  ['fetch-weather'](sessionId, context, cb) {
    // Here should go the api call, e.g.:
    // context.forecast = apiCall(context.loc)
    context.forecast = 'sunny';
    cb(context);
  },
};
```

It is a snipped from the wit.ai node.js client. In my understanding "actions" is an object, and "say", "merge", "error", and "['fetch-weather']" are functions saved as values without key.

How is it possible to define a function without the reserved word "function"?

I also can't comprehend the "['fetch-weather']"-part.

Comment: It's shorthand notation in ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for not finding that one first.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature, [shorthand method names](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), in ES6. It is the same as

```
const a = {
    say: function say(sessionId, context, message, cb) {
        console.log(message);
        cb();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be closing this as a duplicate, not answering it

Answer (score 0):

> I also can't comprehend the "['fetch-weather']"-part.

I suppose it was done because they use a `-` in the function-name.

So `actions.fetch-weather(..);` is **illegal** because the `-` is an operator.

On the other hand, with the `actions['name']`-notation, you can use any name.

Comment: Thanks, I understad that you should use quotation marks when using "-" in a name, but why use the brackets?

Comment: "Why use the brackets?" --> In order to use otherwise illegal names... and also to use computed names, for example you can easy write a new script language using this functionality.

And sorry for that my comment was not clear enough for you, @FrancescoPezzella explained it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible to define a function without the reserved word "function"?

You can find the [answer here](http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties)

> I also can't comprehend the "['fetch-weather']"-part.

That kind of syntax has been introduced by ES6 with a feature called [Computed Property Names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames), in which you can define property names dynamically.

With ES5 you cannot declare an invalid identifier like `fetch-weather` as property directly in an object literal.

ES6:

```
const actions = {
    ...,
    ['fetch-weather'](sessionId, context, cb) {
    },
    ...
};
```

ES5:

```
var actions = {
    // props here
};

actions['fetch-weather'] = function(sessionId, context, cb) {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks Francesco, now I can understand it.